# Blank screen after installing Ubuntu on new ASUS Zenbook with NVIDIA card

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, 19.04

I have a new ASUS Zenboo 14 with NVDIA card.

After a correct Ubuntu 19.04 installation, but only using the "safe graphics" mode, I am not able to open the OS. In fact, after booting, I see only a blank screen.

I tried to fix the issue with some guideline, such as http://kawahara.ca/how-to-fix-a-blank-login-screen-on-a-ubuntu-laptop-with-nvidia-drivers/ but I can't even open the terminal.

Do you know how it can be fixed?

Giulio

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: I've been able to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus Zenbook Pro UX480FD, with several several tries.
In the end I've been able to install nVidia drivers 390 and at boot time I always edit grub line, replacing 'quiet splash' option with a random one 'foo=bar'; surprisingly it works almost every time. PS: I never turn it off, I just leave it in stand by mode closing the lid.